# positioning a node on a path rather than "above" or "below"

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Is there a third alternative for nodes on a path, that means "on" rather than `above` or `below`? The default appears to be `above`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,auto,>=latex, every node/.style={
    font=\sffamily\scriptsize
    },  
    circtext/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=8pt,inner sep=2pt},
    dot/.style={draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=0.6mm,inner sep=0pt}
]
{
\node[circtext, fill=yellow](A) at (0,0) {A};
\node[circtext, fill=yellow, right=of A](B){B};
\draw[->] (A) -- node[dot, pos=0.5, above](C){}(B);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I use `below` I get this:

[image]

But I want it **on** the path, not above or below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even with `auto` active, you can force a `on path` placement adding `anchor=center` in node options:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,auto,>=latex, every node/.style={
    font=\sffamily\scriptsize
    },  
    circtext/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=8pt,inner sep=2pt},
    dot/.style={draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=0.6mm,inner sep=0pt}
]
{
\node[circtext, fill=yellow](A) at (0,0) {A};
\node[circtext, fill=yellow, right=of A](B){B};
\draw[->] (A) -- node[dot, pos=0.25](C){} 
                 node[dot, pos=0.5, anchor=center](C){}  
                 node[dot, pos=0.75, below](C){}(B);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,>=latex, every node/.style={
    font=\sffamily\scriptsize
    },
    circtext/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=8pt,inner sep=2pt},
    dot/.style={draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=0.6mm,inner sep=0pt}
]
{
\node[circtext, fill=yellow](A) at (0,0) {A};
\node[circtext, fill=yellow, right=of A](B){B};
\draw[->] (A) -- node[dot](C){} (B);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I only omit the option `auto`, which causes automatically positioning of nodes above or below the path.

Comment: Thanks! I love the things I can do with tikz, but it's a nightmare to try to find the right combination of incantations. Wish there were a better reference manual.

Comment: ...so there's no way to override `auto`? (i.e. `auto=False` or something)

Comment: @JasonS The manual actually mentions `auto=false` to deactivate the automatic placement. (I've not tried it.)

Comment: Just don't use it.

Comment: Well, I like the `auto` behavior 90% of the time, just not in this case.